# Machine learning, classification type

Tags: machine-learning, classification, gesture-recognition, pattern-recognition

I am studying for my Machine Learning (ML) class and I have question that I couldn't find an answer with my current knowledge. Assume that I have the following data-set,

```
att1 att2 att3 class
5    6    10   a
2    1    5    b
47   8    4    c
4    9    8    a
4    5    6    b
```

The above data-set is clear and I think I can apply classification algorithms for new incoming data after I train my data-set. Since each instance has a label, it is easy to understand that each instance has a class that is labeled with. Now, my question is what if we had a class consisting of different instances such as gesture recognition data. Any class will have multiple instances that specifies its class. For example,

```
xcor ycord depth 
45   100   10
50   20    45
10   51    12
```

the above three instances belong to class A and the below three instances belong to class B as a group, I mean those three data instances constitute that class together. For gesture data, the coordinates of movement of your hand.

```
xcor ycord depth 
45   100   10
50   20    45
10   51    12
```

Now, I want every incoming three instances to be grouped either as A or B? Is it possible to label all of them either A or B without labeling each instance independently? As an example, assume that following group belongs to B, so I want all of the instances to be labelled together as B not individually because of their independent similarity to class A or B? If it is possible, how do we call it?

```
xcor ycord depth 
45   10    10
5    20    87
10   51    44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an scenario where you might want to group an indeterminate number of rows in your dataset as features of a given class. They are either independently associated with a class or they are all features and therefore an unique row. Something like:

```
Instead of
xcor ycord depth 
45   10    10
5    20    87
10   51    44
```

Would be something like:

```
xcor1 ycord1 depth1 xcor2 ycord2 depth2 xcor3 ycord3 depth3  
45      10    10      5    20     87     10     51    44
```

This is pretty much the same approach that is used to model time series

Comment: Thank you. What i was trying to learn was that simple. I just started to study for my class, and I was just curious about how I can model my data if I had this kind of problem. I just couldn't figure out by myself.

Comment: @JohnDavid No problem, we all have this kind of doubts at some point. I was just unsure if that was what you wanted to know. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you may be confused between different types of machine learning.

The dataset given in your class is an example of a **[supervised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) classification** algorithm. That is, given some data and some classes, learn a classifier that can predict classes on new, unseen data. Classifiers that you can apply to this problem include

- [decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree),
- [support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)
- [artificial neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), etc.

The second problem you are describing is an example of an **[unsupervised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) classification** problem. That is, given some data without labels, we want to find an automatic way to separate the different types of data (your A and B) algorithmically. Algorithms that solve this problem include

- [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means)
- [Mixture models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_models)
- [Principal components analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) followed by some sort of clustering

I would look into running a factor analysis or normalizing your data, then running a K-means or gaussian mixture model. This should discover the A and B types of your data if they are distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek at the use of [neural networks for recognizing hand-written text](https://www.google.com/search?q=neural%20network%20handwriting).  You can think of a gesture as a hand-written figure with an additional time component (so, give each pixel an "age".)  If your training data also includes similar time data, then I think the technique should carry over well.

Comment: For example, we have an online hand-written text recognition data-set. Probably it will contain coordinates (x, y) of data for each stroke. So, a group of instances will be labelled as A and other set of instances will be labelled as B. So, for an arbitrary set of coordinates, can we classify all of the incoming coordinates as A or B without labeling each single coordinate as A or B? If you don't understand me, never mind. maybe, i still do not know good enough what i am talking about.